# How to better use ScenarioContext in SpecFlow for maintainability

Tags: c#, cucumber, bdd, specflow

In my Test Project for storing runtime values I use lot of Test Context variables in SpecFlow as below. I use SpecFlow with C# in VS2018.

```
ScenarioContext.Current["PostResponse"] = postResponse;
ScenarioContext.Current["PutResponse"] = putResponse;
```

But currently there were some changes in the implementation and the PUT response need to be changed to POST response for new object creation and remains as it is when updating it. Hence now I have to update every part of Scenario context individually based on scenarios and need to update it. It's not smart way of doing it. I would have stored like "objectcreationResponse", "objectupdateResponse" in one single common place it would have been easier to change in one place. And I use lot of Scneario Context in runtime. Is there any better way of using it?

Comment: What types are the postResponse and putResponse variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can centralize this using C# extension methods:

```
public static class ScenarioContextExtensions
{
    public static UpdateResponseType GetUpdateReponse(this ScenarioContext context)
    {
        return context["updateResponse"] as UpdateResponseType;
    }

    public static void SetUpdateResponse(this ScenarioContext context, UpdateResponseType updateResponse)
    {
        return context["updateResponse"] = updateResponse;
    }
}
```

Now any place you have a ScenarioContext object, you have strongly typed getters and setters for this common information:

```
ScenarioContext.Current.GetUpdateResponse();
ScenarioContext.Current.SetUpdateResponse(...);
```

This allows you to leverage all of the refactoring tools available in Visual Studio, which should alleviate the problem you describe.